# Magnetized nail lifting another nail

Tags: electromagnetism

I have two nails (made of Fe). A and B.

A can not lift B. 
If I rub A on the magnets north pole, then it can lift B. 
Then if I rub it again but on the south pole, it can not lift B.

why is that? Why cant it lift B anymore?

the title I have chosen for this question is really bad. If someone else got a better idea please edit. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iron is composed of small [magnetic dipoles](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/357033/magnetic-dipole) all with their north south axis pointing randomly.

By rubbing the nail in a consistent specific direction the small dipoles line up with the magnetic field, so when you are rubbing the north pole, the dipoles align
 south-north. Thus you get a small magnet, not permanent because the little dipoles are not frozen in a crystal.

When you take this nail and rub it on the south pole you essentially demagnetize it for a while, if you take the same time you took on the north pole. If you persist in rubbing,  the dipoles will align the other way and you will have a small magnet again.